# Does coarse location use less battery than geofences on Android?

Tags: android, performance, gps

I'm trying to know when your device leaves your home, but I don't need fine GPS location nor high update rate (i.e. it's fine if I know the user is out only 10 minutes after he left his home and he's already 100 meters away).

Which of the two solutions should use less battery (both should use already less battery than plain GPS location listener)?

1. [Receiving Location Updates | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`
2. [Creating and Monitoring Geofences | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

The first is for sure using a more battery saving solution and I can control the frequency to be low.

The second is a higher level API which does just what I want but I've no idea what it does and it looks like it'll use fine GPS location constantly while the user is within the geofence (remember I want to reduce battery usage).

Anyone has some insight on this regarding mostly battery usage?

Comment: Or check if the wireless connection with your home router is lost.

Comment: @greenapps Yes that's part of it but it's not enough as Wi-Fi may not be always accessible from each room in the house.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here might be a combination of things. The [Location and battery Drain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81W61JA6YHw&index=7&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) video explains more about how the GPS & Location chips burn up battery in your device. ([Battery Drain and Networking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY&index=13&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) will detail how the Radio chips work.)

Basically, using a [FusedLocationProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) will allow you to scale back accuracy vs. power drain. Basically less-resolution results in less battery drain.

Knowing that, I'd suggest a set of low-power checks as early-warnings before moving to the higher-power checks:

1. Use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to determine if the mobile device is on the CellularNetwork or not. If they are, there's a good chance they've moved outside of the wifi boundries.
2. Check if the WiFi they are connected to is the common home WiFi (so you don't mistake the coffeeshop wifi as home).
3. Use a back-off system on your checks. If the user is home, chances are, they will be there for a while; so scale back how often you check position.
4. If the user is on Cell network, use a Course Location to determine if you're within 100ft of your known home location.
5. Use a Fine location check to resolve issues / corner cases with the Course Location check.
6. When all else fails, do a Geo Fencing check; but then turn it off as soon as you've resolved the issues.

Basically, you want the least-power draining options to run the most often, and only use the most power-draining when you're resolving discrepancies in position.

Comment: Your steps are good when doing things manually. I'm wondering a bit why or more if Geofencing of Google Play Services is doing all that (or most of it) already.

Comment: After digging it seems that Google Play Services Geofencing also does most of those in some form or another and that the result is a low battery usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few hints in the documentation that Google wants you to use the Geofencing (or the new Awareness API) for your use case.

The first method need to be triggered from a LocationRequest, and from 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

> Activities should strongly consider removing all location request when entering the background (for example at onPause()), or at least swap the request to a larger interval and lower quality.

This shows that this API is designed to be used only when your application is active, hence the "Request" term.

Google soon realized that a lot of apps (including their own Google Now) are requesting for location in the background, and they want to improve it in such a way that the requests can be pooled and shared, hence they created Geofencing and eventually Awareness API.

From the Fence API document,

https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview#fences_and_snapshots

> Fence API lets your app react to the user's current situation, and provides notification when a combination of context conditions are met. For example, "tell me whenever the user is walking and their headphones are plugged in". Once a fence is registered, the Fence API can send callbacks to your app even when it's not running.

So, in your use case, if your app is not running, you should be using the second method.